# Objective C - access SOAP service with ws-security using client side certificate

Tags: objective-c, soap, x509certificate, ws-security

I want to access a SOAP service with ws-security using client side certificate. It there any direct ways or third party lib for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Sudzc](http://sudzc.com) site to help you generate code based on a WSDL. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/kirbyt/360idev/tree/8da9a5a1c2ee3825f195abc878276244a774f33f/SOAP).